# How to make external url as homepage

Tags: joomla-3.4, administrator, url

I own a live website and I'm attempting to replace the current homepage using an external url as menu item, the external url is an index.html. This way the browser should open that page first but that's not happening.

The browser keep redirecting me to the old homepage that is a single article menu item. I truly hope to have been clear enough  and here is the live web site address http://www.farmhousebriganti.com here you will see what I'm talking about. P.S. the single article menu item is the homepage till when I have attempted to replace it with an external url menu item whose link url is index.html.

I'm aware this problem might have an easy solution but believe me I've been stuck with it for days now. If the live web site address is not enough and for any further information just ask

Comment: Is index.html hosted on the same server?

Comment: Yes it is but I can't understand why you asked me this question is it a relevant matter????

Comment: I wouldn't waste my time asking if it wasn't. I'm glad you found a suitable answer.

Comment: Hey man don't misunderstand me I didn't mean that was a waste of time I just didn't understand it and I'm glad you asked me that question because it's never too late to learn something new

Comment: I was confused as to what you meant by external url and was just clarifying. Anyway I was just going to suggest you incorporate the index.html content into your article, but I see FFrewin has already mentioned this.

Comment: And you should have also read my comment to his answer where I have clarified why I decided not to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla `.htaccess` uses `index.php` by default. You can edit `.htaccess` and add these to the end of it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule .* index.html [L]
```

This means, that root url will show `index.html` and other url's (deeper) will use `index.php`.

Comment: congratulations man

Answer (score 1):

As Rene posted in his answer, loading Joomla's home page (index.php) instead of your index.html, is because of .htaccess that forcing parsing of index.php first over index.html files.

So following Rene's instructions you can change this.

However I see a potential problem by having a external html page as home page instead of your Joomla site.

To answer directly the question in the title of your question:

You can't have a menu item of type: external URL as home page. Joomla needs one way or another to have a default home page menu item. And it won't allow this be an external url.
So what's going to be your Joomla's home page?

I think it can be possible if you create a hidden menu and put there your home page menu item, so it won't exist in your main menu.

Other than that, whatever the desired html page for home page would be, I would still stick and create it within Joomla.

Comment: First and foremost I want to thank you for your reply man. Well the fact is that I already have an "internal" homepage as you can see on my live website address. The need for an external homepage comes from the bootstrap design as you know if you use the joomla default homepage the boostrap is automatically loaded in the head of index.php so you can't use the bootstrap cdn and you could not need it but as regards the design I found myself at ease using an external url since I've been able to keep the wanted design that otherwise I should have edited